# how to get the value of an object in Entity before applying SaveChanges()?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

Here my case is simple i need to get a property of one object. The problem is the object is still in the memory, I did not applied the SaveChanges() So I cannot query against the database. So I need to query against the Cached Object inside the Entity. How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DbSet.Local` property.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.local%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: Note that the `Local` property is also part of the `IDbSet` interface, so it can be used even if the context uses that.